# Computed Columns - Needs an Introduction 

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Question is the title itself. I was asked to use computed columns in SQL Server. But when I searched about it in Google, I found it was mainly for displaying the combined values of more than one coloumn. And usage of this may reduce performance if it is treated as a permanent coloumn. So I like to know

1. Advantages and disadvantages
2. When and where we need to implement this

Please guide me how can I achieve a solution for the below problem, if possible (with Compute columns. If not possible why?). Or any other way to implement this requirement. 
My requirement is to use a colomn which will identify which coloumn of that table was updated.
So I can compare the values and identify the changes.

**EDIT** : table structure below.

```
table structure
 ColA int ID (PK) - autonumber.
 ColB Nvarchar
 ColC Nvarchar
 ColD Int
 ColE Int
 ColF Nvarchar

-- Updatation can happen any one the coloumns other than ColA
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question in the title is different from in your text. Seems you don't actually want a list of pros and cons of computed columns in general but are asking whether it is possible/suitable for your specific scenario? (Answer: It is not possible BTW and you would need a trigger unless I haven't understood exactly what you are trying to do)

Comment: You could use a compound case expression (one case expression per column) to compute a bitmask that represents column changes. If you you post a code example of the table you are working with, we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: @isme: any reason not to use COLUMNS_UPDATED() instead of rolling your own?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need triggers, not calculated columns.  Your last sentence states that you want to "compare the values and identify the changes.".  What is your end goal?  Are you trying to persist this information so that future data readers will have that information available?  Or is it for your own programming needs so that when the data changes you can accomplish something programatically? In both cases a trigger would give you the opportunity to interrogate what is changing when it's changing.  You can use COLUMNS_UPDATED() like @isme: suggested inside the trigger.